# Behavior of tar --exclude-ignore not as expected

Tags: linux, tar

If I have the file structure

```
dir/
dir/.ignore
dir/file.ext
dir/subdir/
dir/subdir/other_file.ext
```

where `dir/.ignore` contains one line, `*.ext`, then I would expect the command

```
$ tar -czvf dir.tgz --exclude-ignore=.ignore dir
```

to result in a `dir.tgz` that contains `dir/.ignore` and `dir/subdir/other_file.ext`, but not `dir/file.ext`.

Yet running that command using GNU tar version 1.34 (as included with Ubuntu 22.04) gives:

```
$ tar -czvf dir.tgz --exclude-ignore=.ignore dir
dir/
dir/subdir/
dir/.ignore
```

so `dir/subdir/other_file.ext` is not included in `dir.tgz`.

The man page says:

> ```
>   --exclude-ignore=FILE
>          Before dumping a directory, see if it contains FILE.  If so, read exclusion
>          patterns from this file. The patterns affect only the directory itself.
> ```

and the specific alternative

> ```
>   --exclude-ignore-recursive=FILE
>          Same as --exclude-ignore, except that patterns from FILE affect both the 
>          directory and all its subdirectories.
> ```

Yet the exclusion pattern in `dir/.ignore` is applied to `dir/subdir` anyway?

To pre-empt the obvious: no, there is not accidentally a `.ignore` in `dir/subdir/` as well.

Comment: https://www.mail-archive.com/bug-tar@gnu.org/msg05873.html

Comment: Thanks. I didn't expect it to actually be a bug in tar... If you make that an answer I'll accept that as the answer. I also reported it as a bug in their bugtracker, with a reference to that mailinglist post. Perhaps that'll help to get it solved.

Comment: I made a [community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/355310) answer. You can edit the answer and mention your bug report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably a bug, [already encountered](https://www.mail-archive.com/bug-tar@gnu.org/msg05873.html).

> I've found that `--exclude-ignore` option and `--exclude-vcs-ignores` with `.cvsignore` act recursively, which contradicts the manual.

Apparently not fixed yet.

Now also reported [in their bugtracker](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?64387)